# What is the advantage of the new print function in Python 3.x over the Python 2 print statement?

Tags: python, function, printing, python-3.x, python-2.x

I've heard several times that print being a function (3.x) is better than it being a statement (2.x). But why?

I was a fan of it being a statement mainly because it allowed me to type two less characters (ie, the parentheses).

I'd be interested to see some situations where the print statement just doesn't cut it, and a function is superior.

Comment: @LennartRegebro: It’s not just two characters: the whole flow feels different. Not having it as statement incurs a cost - especially for those used to the statement. But it relieves quite some pains in corner cases.

Comment: Yeah, now you have to track extra parentheses, making concatenating many strings slightly more annoying if you're also embedding in-line string replacements with tuples.  I'm definitely getting more typos/invalid syntax erros in Py3 because of this!  It's caused me to now use a variable to generate the printed text.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Everything from [Jochen's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6239909/2688027) and [Sven's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6239919/2688027), plus:

You can use `print()` it in places where you can't use `print`, such as:

```
[print(x) for x in range(10)]
```

Comment: I intentionally did not mention this one, since I could not think of any use which I would recommend using `print()` as an expression rather than a statement for.  Your example creates an unneeded list of 10 times the values `None`, and it would be certainly better to use `for x in range(10): print(x)`.

Comment: @Sven: Sure. I certainly didn't intend it to be the accepted answer. :)

Comment: I just tried to use a print in a lambda, where a class was allowing me to pass a function to log values with. I wanted to just print them out. I had to define a function elsewhere because you can't write `lambda x: print x` :(.

Comment: It also made it easier for the smart people who build the language Python to add such functionality as a different separator

Answer (score 58):

> ## Rationale
>
> The print statement has long appeared on lists of dubious language features that are to be removed in Python 3000, such as Guido's "Python Regrets" presentation [[1]](https://legacy.python.org/doc/essays/ppt/regrets/PythonRegrets.pdf). As such, the objective of this PEP is not new, though it might become much disputed among Python developers.
>
> The following arguments for a print() function are distilled from a python-3000 message by Guido himself [[2]](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2005-September/056154.html):
>
> - print is the only application-level functionality that has a statement dedicated to it. Within Python's world, syntax is generally used as a last resort, when something *can't* be done without help from the compiler. Print doesn't qualify for such an exception.
> - At some point in application development one quite often feels the need to replace print output by something more sophisticated, like logging calls or calls into some other I/O library. With a print() function, this is a straightforward string replacement, today it is a mess adding all those parentheses and possibly converting >>stream style syntax.
> - Having special syntax for print puts up a much larger barrier for evolution, e.g. a hypothetical new printf() function is not too far fetched when it will coexist with a print() function.
> - There's no easy way to convert print statements into another call if one needs a different separator, not spaces, or none at all. Also, there's no easy way *at all* to conveniently print objects with some other separator than a space.
> - If print() is a function, it would be much easier to replace it within one module (just `def print(*args):...`) or even throughout a program (e.g. by putting a different function in `__builtin__.print`). As it is, one can do this by writing a class with a write() method and assigning that to sys.stdout – that's not bad, but definitely a much larger conceptual leap, and it works at a different level than print.
>
> — [PEP 3105 – Make print a function](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3105/)

Comment: Nice, but doesn't address why an *expression* (function-call) can be easier to deal with than a *statement* in terms of grammar constructs, most notably a simple `lambda`.

Answer (score 37):

One advantage of `print` being a function is consistency.  There is no reason for it to be a statement.  Compare these two lines

```
2.x: print >> my_file, x
3.x: print(x, file=my_file)
```

The new version looks much more like Python, doesn't it?

Another advantage of the function version is flexibility.  For example, if you want to catch all `print` calls for debugging purposes, you can now simply redefine `print`:

```
def print(*args, **kwargs):
    # whatever
    __builtins__.print(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: re “The new version looks much more like Python, doesn't it?”: they're both valid Python, aren't they? I believe you meant “pythonic”, but even “pythonic” is quite vague. I don't disagree with your answer, I just find your question to be an insufficient argument for the `print` function. (Delegation of the answer to the OP is for psychologists and managers, I think :)

Comment: ΤΖΩΤΖΙΟΥ: I said it's about consistency.  This is not a hard fact, so I have to leave the judgement ultimately to the reader.  I could make it "In my opinion, the new version looks more like Python" if you prefer. :)

Answer (score 18):

I thought over this question and had no idea about pros of python 3 version. But when I needed to print the columns of `pandas.DataFrame` (without `Index([...])`), I've found out that

```
print *df.columns
```

throws an exception, while

```
print(*df.columns)
```

works fine! And if you want to have same (configurable) print options in several call prints, you can save them to dictionary and pass as `**print_options`

So at least `*args`, `**kw_args` tricks are a good reason for `print` to be a function!

Answer (score 12):

You can replace the built-in `print` by a custom one:

```
import os
import sys

def print(s):
   sys.stderr.write('Will now print ' + str(s) + '.' + os.linesep)
   sys.stdout.write(str(s) + os.linesep)

print(['A', 'list'])
# Output: 
# stderr: Will now print ['A', 'list'].
# stdout: ['A', 'list']
```

You can use `print` inside a lambda or a function call etc.:

```
example_timeout_function(call=lambda: print('Hello world'), timeout=5)
do_things(print_function=print)
```