# Python Invalid syntax - Invalid syntax

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following piece of code to pull the names of all files within a particular folder (including all files in it's subfolders):

```
import sys,os

root = "C:\Users\myName\Box Sync\Projects\Project_Name"
path = os.path.join(root, "Project_Name")

for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(root):
    for name in files:
        print os.path.join(path, name)
```

Unfortunately, it throws the following error:

```
>   File "<ipython-input-7-2fff411deea4>", line 8
>     print os.path.join(path, name)
>            ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I'm trying to execute the script in Jupyter Notebook. I also tried saving it as a .py file and running it through Anaconda prompt but received the same error. Can someone please point out where I'm going wrong? I'm pretty new to Python.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in `python3`, print function needs to be like this :

```
print(os.path.join(path, name))
```

For more information on the changes within print function from python 2 to 3, check these links :

- [print is a function](https://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#print-is-a-function)
- [pep-3105](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3105/)
- [What is the advantage of the new print function in Python 3.x over the Python 2 print statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6239887/what-is-the-advantage-of-the-new-print-function-in-python-3-x-over-the-python-2)

Answer (score 1):

This is a Python 2 Vs Python 3 issue.

In Python 2, `print` is used without parenthesis like:

```
print 42
```

In Python 3, `print` is a function and has to be called with parenthesis like:

```
print(42)
```