# Can return call functions?

Tags: python

I tried this code from a Python tutorial:

```
def func1(a):
    return a ** a
def func2(a):
    return func1(a) * func1(a)
print(func2(2))
```

It displays `16`, and I am trying to understand how this works.

Does `func1` get called when the `return` statement starts to run?

Can `return` call functions?

I tried to understand how it works by adding a `print`:

```
def func1(a):
    print("Hello World")
    return a ** a
def func2(a):
    return func1(a) * func1(a)
print(func2(2))
```

I see that the `Hello World` message is printed two times, so I assume that `func1` is getting called twice. How exactly does this work? Is the `*` in this line related to how it works?

Comment: Return isn't doing anything. `func1(a) * func1(a)` 
is  an expression that gets evaluated to some value *first*. That value is then returned.

Comment: Is the confusion related what the "*" does? func1(2) returns 2^2=4 since ** is an exponential. so func1(2)*func1(2)=4*4=16. Then the return on func2 returns this value. Can you clarify any points of confusion?

Comment: Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57518639/

Answer (score 1):

### Expressions

When code says something like `func1(2)`, this is an [*expression*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4728073). The term "expression" comes from mathematics. Specifically, this expression is a *call* of the function `func1`, passing it an [*argument*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/156767) `2`. When the function is called, it will receive the value `2`, assigning it to the `a` *parameter* (i.e., naming it `a`).

Expressions can be simpler than that. An individual variable name by itself is *also* an expression. It simply evaluates to whatever that variable is naming, in the current context. So is a literal value, like `2`. It evaluates, unsurprisingly, to itself.

Expressions can also be more complex than that. They can be composed of other expressions. So we can write `1 + 2 * 3`, and it is *evaluated* (after figuring out the [operator precedence](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence)) by computing `2 * 3` to get `6`, and then `1 + 6` to get 7. **The result from evaluating each step, substitutes in to the next step**. The *same thing* happens with calls to functions. We can write, for example, `func1(func1(2))`; the inner `func1(2)` is evaluated to `4`, and so the next step is to *call `func1(4)`*, resulting in `256`. Or we can write something like `func1(2) * func1(2)`; the calls happen first, evaluating to `4` each time, and then `4 * 4` results in `16`.

But **why** did the calls evaluate that way? Because of the `return` statements in the functions they called. So now we also need to understand statements.

### Statements

An expression is one kind of *statement* in Python. Statements are the individual steps in a running program - normally, a single line of code.

The point is, we can write an expression on a line by itself in Python, and that is one kind of statement. The result is computed, and then thrown away. (How is this useful? Because the expression could have side effects, for example, assigning to a global variable, or raising an exception. Python is so flexible that, most of the time, it would be necessary to actually evaluate an expression in order to figure out whether it could have a side effect. So, Python doesn't forbid writing code like that, and even "obviously" useless things like `1 + 1` on a line by itself are allowed. (There is, however, one special case: docstrings are [given special treatment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/713138).))

Another important statement in this code is the *`return` statement*. This consists of the keyword `return` statement, optionally followed by... an expression.

**The purpose of the `return` statement is to state [the result of evaluating the call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3052793)**. `return` [means](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7129285): "evaluate this expression, and then exit the current function. The result of evaluating the expression is the result of evaluating the function call, so there is no more work to do in this function." (When it appears by itself, [`return` in Python means the same thing as `return None`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15300550), which [also happens if the function reaches the end without a `return` statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067013) - that is to say, in those cases, the function call evaluates to [special value `None`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19473185).)

So: in `func2`, `return func1(a) * func1(a)` means that `func1(a) * func1(a)` will be evaluated, resulting in `16` - because `func1(a)` was evaluated twice, and the result both times was `4`, and `4 * 4` gives `16`. Thus, **that is the result of evaluating the function call**.

(But why did `func1(a)` evaluate to `4`? By the same reasoning. Each time, `func1` was given a value of `2` - `func2`'s value named `a` - for its own `a`. It computed `a ** a`, i.e., `2 ** 2`, getting `4`, and `return`ed that.)

At the top level, `print(func2(2))` will therefore **call `func2(2)` first**, evaluating to `16`, and then pass `16` to `print` (in Python 3.x, [`print` is a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25445439)). `print` will display the text as a side effect (remember the bit above about side effects?) and [return `None`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27959258), which is then ignored (because this statement in the code is just an expression by itself). (In 2.x, [`print` was a statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6239887), with its own special syntax. This accomplished a similar goal, but with a lot of subtle differences.)

So, pedantically, no - `return` doesn't "call" other functions; functions are called by... calling them. `return` can be followed by an expression, and its job is to report (in other words... return) the result of that expression, from the current function, to the place where it was called. But the expression written after `return` is **just an expression**, following the normal rules; so it can contain more calls to other functions. (Or even the same function again - this is called [*recursion*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/717725), and is the basis of some powerful techniques.)

Answer (score 0):

`return` is executed last. The expression will be evaluated first.

`func1(2)` returns 2 ** 2, which is 4.
It is getting called twice, which is why `Hello World` is being printed twice.

4 * 4 is 16.

Now that the expression is evaluated, `func2` will now return 16.

`return` is a keyword that stops the function(and returns the value you put after), so everything else in that line will have to be executed first.